# iframe I want to use src 's text box and password fileds

Tags: asp.net, iframe

Hi I have a website. In this website I have an iframe

// Can I use username text box and password text box of source page in my Ifram. So that I can fill value in them and then click the login button programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do that in javascript if the src is from same domain:

```
var userid = document.frames['LoginFrame'].getElementById('UserID');
var password = document.frames['LoginFrame'].getElementById('password');
```